# How to syntax highlight additional keywords in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to highlight some additional keywords in Vim beyond the default syntax highlighting script.

Trying the following in .vimrc (I'd like to keep everything in one file) but it is not working:

```
au FileType haskell syn keyword hsfunc filter map foldl foldr flip 
au FileType haskell syn keyword hsfunc fmap zip curry uncurry 
au FileType haskell hi hsfunc ctermfg=white
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 4):

The *ftplugin* stuff is executed **before** the syntax scripts, so your `:autocmd`s define the additional keywords only to have them cleared by the default `syntax/haskell.vim` later on.

You can try using `:autocmd Syntax haskell ...` instead, but the correct way is to put the `:syn keyword` commands into the file `~/.vim/after/syntax/haskell.vim`.

While it may be tempting to keep all config in one place, this doesn't scale well. Better use the abstractions that Vim offers, or you'll end up with an indecipherable thousand+ lines `~/.vimrc` eventually, too.